# Can Ubuntu create another partition when is installing?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I only have one partition created and i was thinking, if i wanna have Ubuntu and Windows, can Ubuntu create another partition for itself in the process of installing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can, and has to. Since Windows doesn't support creating an `ext4` partition, the installer has to do that itself.

There are a few ways to create a partition during the install process. The easiest way is to just run the installer and tell it to "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows."

If that option doesn't show up, or you want more control, choose to "Try Ubuntu" when booting from the install media. You can then open Gparted and manually resize your Windows partition to create space for Ubuntu.
Once you finish the partitioning, hit the "Apply" button and open the installer when Gparted is finished processing. In the installer, choose the "Something Else..." option and choose to mount the newly created `ext4` partition as `/` to Install to it.

Sorry for the somewhat abbreviated instructions. I'm doing this all from my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. My experience is limited to Windows 7.  I Installed Windows 7 first, intentionally wiping the entire drive in the process.  After that, I installed Ubuntu, choosing the "Install alongside Windows 7" which is the first option.  From there, the installer let me choose how much disk space to allocate to each OS.

After installing Ubuntu, there were some minor issues the first time I booted Windows 7 but these were fixed automatically and I have had no problems booting either OS.  From everything I've seen on this board, Windows 8 and higher have serious with dual-boot.